# Mongo Shell script to modify DateTime to valueOf() in milliseconds, Epoch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, datetime, graphql

Because GraphQL doesn't use the DateTime scalar, I have decided to convert all the fields in my MongoDB database collections that are of the type, DateTime, into Integer, representing DateTime as milliseconds. I have about 8,000+ documents that need to be modified and created a script to do the work.

The script was supposed to create a new field "publishedID", Integer scalar, to correspond with the "published" field. When I loaded my script, all the documents were over written, leaving only the DateTime field - although, as I intended, in milliseconds - but all the other fields, such as, "title", "image", "body", "subtitle", including other DateTime types like, "modified" and "created", etc. were deleted.

Below is the script I ran:

```
db.Post.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
  let currentDate = new Date(myDoc.published);
  print(currentDate);
  db.Post.update(
     { published: currentDate },
     { publishedID: currentDate.valueOf() }
  );
});
```

I had hoped the ISO DateTimes, previously set for the "published" field would just have been converted to milliseconds, I got that. But I did not want everything else in the document deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are missing the `$set` operator in the update query which is the root cause of all fields deletion in the documents

```
db.Post.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
  let currentDate = new Date(myDoc.published);
  print(currentDate);
  db.Post.update(
     { published: currentDate },
     { $set: {publishedID: currentDate.valueOf()} } // $set: {} added
  );
});
```

`$set` operator updates the given fields but here we have added one field only which will replace the existing fields in the matched collections.

Comment: Thank you and please consider accepting my answer. @OptimistPrime

Comment: Also, if anyone cares, the mongoDB Integer type has limits so divide by 1000, to do seconds instead of milliseconds.